# Passing a function with parameters as columns within double loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, mapply, calculation

I have a problem in applying a function (some formula) which takes two parameters (two columns) and iterates through them within the data frame. So I have 20 variables and I want the function to recalculate all combinations of two variables and save the result in a variable (so in a way, the script should create 3 x 3 = 9 new variables). So I am thinking to use a double loop.

example:

```
dflist1 <- c(dat$DIM1, dat$DIM2, dat$DIM3)
k = 1
    for (i in dflist1) {
        for (j in dflist1) {
```

However, then I wish to apply function, which contains formula (and takes two parameters: one as one column and second as another column).

Example of function:

```
calc <- function(i,j)
{
    abs(i*j)/(i*j)*log(1+abs(i*j))
}

calc(i = dat$DIM1, j = dat$DIM2)
```

so back to for loop's - here comes the problem, when I try to apply the function and save it in another column, it only saves last calculated result (I haven't yet set the iteration of newly created variables):

```
for (i in dflist1) {

    for (j in dflist1) {

    dat$kk <- mapply(FUN = calc, i, j, SIMPLIFY = TRUE)
    print(dat$kk)
    }

k = k + 1

}
```

Can someone please help me with that? So I need to iterate calculation (by row) through all combos of columns and write results in new columns.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `data.table` solution uses the `CJ()` *cross join* function to create the 3 x 3 pairs of input parameters to the `calc()` function, `dcast()` to reshape the computed results from long to wide format, and a *join* to append the 9 computed columns to the original data.frame:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, rn := .I]
df[df[, CJ(c(a, b, c), c(a, b, c)), by = rn][
  , value := calc(V1, V2)][
    , dcast(.SD, rn ~ rowid(rn))], on = .(rn)][, !"rn"]
```

> ```
>                 a           b          c           1            2           3            4
>    1: -0.56047565 -0.99579872 -0.5116037 0.688945918  0.443480566  0.41174822  0.443480566
>    2: -0.23017749 -1.03995504  0.2369379 0.733091907  0.214606608 -0.22026320  0.214606608
>    3:  1.55870831 -0.01798024 -0.5415892 0.257211652  0.009690796 -0.61203449  0.009690796
>    4:  0.07050839 -0.13217513  1.2192276 0.017319415 -0.009276298 -0.14941225 -0.009276298
>    5:  0.12928774 -2.54934277  0.1741359 2.014789492 -0.284877208 -0.36736997 -0.284877208
>   ---                                                                                     
>  996: -0.08997520  0.07664366  1.0609662 0.008062943 -0.006872360 -0.09117496 -0.006872360
>  997:  1.07051604  0.25516476 -0.4455056 0.181050147 -0.107667460 -0.38995947 -0.107667460
>  998: -1.35110039  0.27744682 -0.4291802 1.038675520  0.457339699 -0.31835082  0.457339699
>  999: -0.52261670  0.53685602  1.1890118 0.241477031 -0.247305230 -0.48328838 -0.247305230
> 1000: -0.24919068 -0.46048557  0.8342941 0.192310630  0.108629008 -0.32510818  0.108629008
>                  5           6           7           8          9
>    1: 0.2731770948  0.25211300  0.41174822  0.25211300 0.23249043
>    2: 0.0516258319 -0.05310253 -0.22026320 -0.05310253 0.05462033
>    3: 0.0003232368 -0.02764041 -0.61203449 -0.02764041 1.23243536
>    4: 0.0049591165  0.08246971 -0.14941225  0.08246971 0.91088256
>    5: 0.0165771550  0.02226394 -0.36736997  0.02226394 0.02987264
>   ---                                                            
>  996: 0.0058570650  0.07817913 -0.09117496  0.07817913 0.75407734
>  997: 0.0630771939  0.24150040 -0.38995947  0.24150040 0.76360778
>  998: 0.1690637292 -0.11250215 -0.31835082 -0.11250215 0.07415780
>  999: 0.2532570646  0.49367630 -0.48328838  0.49367630 0.88118117
> 1000: 0.0602443085 -0.18888191 -0.32510818 -0.18888191 0.52830001
> ```

Note that the computed values may appear in different columns when comparing with [LAP's result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48057542/3817004).

#### Edit: Improved version for commutative function

Apparently, OP's function definition is commutative, i.e., `calc(1, 2)` returns the same value as `calc(2, 1)`. This is why we find only 6 different computed values in each row.

In case of a commutative function we can save the computation of 3 duplicate values. So instead of doing a full cross join

```
CJ(1:3, 1:3)
```

> ```
>    V1 V2
> 1:  1  1
> 2:  1  2
> 3:  1  3
> 4:  2  1
> 5:  2  2
> 6:  2  3
> 7:  3  1
> 8:  3  2
> 9:  3  3
> ```

we can use only unique combinations

```
CJ(1:3, 1:3)[V1 <= V2]
```

> ```
>    V1 V2
> 1:  1  1
> 2:  1  2
> 3:  1  3
> 4:  2  2
> 5:  2  3
> 6:  3  3
> ```

Note that this is just an illustrative example to explain the effect and can not be used stand-alone.

We need to modify the complete `data.table` expression:

```
df[df[, CJ(c(a, b, c), c(a, b, c), sorted = FALSE)[V1 <= V2], by = rn][
  , value := calc(V1, V2)][
    , dcast(.SD, rn ~ rowid(rn))], on = .(rn)][, !"rn"]
```

> ```
>                 a           b          c           1            2           3
>    1: -0.56047565 -0.99579872 -0.5116037 0.688945918  0.443480566  0.41174822
>    2: -0.23017749 -1.03995504  0.2369379 0.733091907  0.214606608 -0.22026320
>    3:  1.55870831 -0.01798024 -0.5415892 0.257211652  0.009690796 -0.61203449
>    4:  0.07050839 -0.13217513  1.2192276 0.017319415 -0.009276298 -0.14941225
>    5:  0.12928774 -2.54934277  0.1741359 2.014789492 -0.284877208 -0.36736997
>   ---                                                                        
>  996: -0.08997520  0.07664366  1.0609662 0.008062943 -0.006872360 -0.09117496
>  997:  1.07051604  0.25516476 -0.4455056 0.181050147 -0.107667460 -0.38995947
>  998: -1.35110039  0.27744682 -0.4291802 1.038675520  0.457339699 -0.31835082
>  999: -0.52261670  0.53685602  1.1890118 0.241477031 -0.247305230 -0.48328838
> 1000: -0.24919068 -0.46048557  0.8342941 0.192310630  0.108629008 -0.32510818
>                  4           5          6
>    1: 0.2731770948  0.25211300 0.23249043
>    2: 0.0516258319 -0.05310253 0.05462033
>    3: 0.0003232368 -0.02764041 1.23243536
>    4: 0.0049591165  0.08246971 0.91088256
>    5: 0.0165771550  0.02226394 0.02987264
>   ---                                    
>  996: 0.0058570650  0.07817913 0.75407734
>  997: 0.0630771939  0.24150040 0.76360778
>  998: 0.1690637292 -0.11250215 0.07415780
>  999: 0.2532570646  0.49367630 0.88118117
> 1000: 0.0602443085 -0.18888191 0.52830001
> ```

Note that `sorted = FALSE` is required to keep the order of values as supplied to `CJ()`. `CJ()` will sort the values by default.

#### Edit 2: Saving to type column names

In case there are many more column names, it might be cumbersome to type all the column names twice for the *cross join*.

This can solved by the following modification:

```
df[df[, CJ(do.call("c", .SD), do.call("c", .SD), sorted = FALSE), by = rn][u
  , value := calc(V1, V2)][
    , dcast(.SD, rn ~ rowid(rn))], on = .(rn)][, !"rn"]
```

or

```
df[df[, CJ(do.call("c", .SD), do.call("c", .SD), sorted = FALSE)[V1 <= V2], by = rn][
  , value := calc(V1, V2)][
    , dcast(.SD, rn ~ rowid(rn))], on = .(rn)][, !"rn"]
```

for the commutative case.

`do.call()` *constructs and executes a function call from a name or a function and a list of arguments to be passed to it.* (see `help(do.call)`). `.SD` is a special symbol which denotes the subset of data for each group, excluding any columns used in `by`. As we are grouping by each row, here, `.SD` is a list with one value of each column which is passed to the `c()` function.

By referring to `.SD`, all columns of `df` are used in the *cross join*, except those in the `by` parameter. However, we can specify the columns to be included in the *cross join* with the `.SDcols` parameter, e.g.

```
df[df[, CJ(do.call("c", .SD), do.call("c", .SD), sorted = FALSE)[V1 <= V2], by = rn, 
      .SDcols = 1:2][
        , value := calc(V1, V2)][
          , dcast(.SD, rn ~ rowid(rn))], on = .(rn)][, !"rn"]
```

will only use the first two columns of `df`

> ```
>                 a           b          c            1            2           3
>    1: -0.56047565 -0.99579872 -0.5116037 0.6889459178  0.443480566 0.273177095
>    2: -0.23017749 -1.03995504  0.2369379 0.7330919071  0.214606608 0.051625832
>    3:  1.55870831 -0.01798024 -0.5415892 0.0003232368 -0.027640410 1.232435358
>    4:  0.07050839 -0.13217513  1.2192276 0.0173194151 -0.009276298 0.004959116
>    5:  0.12928774 -2.54934277  0.1741359 2.0147894919 -0.284877208 0.016577155
>   ---                                                                         
>  996: -0.08997520  0.07664366  1.0609662 0.0080629430 -0.006872360 0.005857065
>  997:  1.07051604  0.25516476 -0.4455056 0.0630771939  0.241500405 0.763607781
>  998: -1.35110039  0.27744682 -0.4291802 1.0386755196 -0.318350818 0.074157797
>  999: -0.52261670  0.53685602  1.1890118 0.2414770311 -0.247305230 0.253257065
> 1000: -0.24919068 -0.46048557  0.8342941 0.1923106299  0.108629008 0.060244308
> ```

#### Edit 3: Preserving the order of combinations when dropping duplicates

The parameter `sorted = FALSE` is required but not sufficient to keep the created combinations always in the same order according to the column numbering. This is caused by `[V1 <= V2]` comparing *values* but *not positions* of columns.

So we have to make sure that always the same rows are removed from the table of combinations. Here is a small example:

```
test <- data.table(rn = 1:3, 
                   a = LETTERS[c(3L, 1:2)],
                   b = LETTERS[c(2:3, 1L)], 
                   c = LETTERS[1:3])
test
```

> ```
>    rn a b c
> 1:  1 C B A
> 2:  2 A C B
> 3:  3 B A C
> ```

```
# dropping duplicates by value
test[, CJ(c(a, b, c), c(a, b, c), sorted = FALSE)[,cn := .I][V1 <= V2], by = rn]
```

> ```
>     rn V1 V2 cn
>  1:  1  C  C  1
>  2:  1  B  C  4
>  3:  1  B  B  5
>  4:  1  A  C  7
>  5:  1  A  B  8
>  6:  1  A  A  9
>  7:  2  A  A  1
>  8:  2  A  C  2
>  9:  2  A  B  3
> 10:  2  C  C  5
> 11:  2  B  C  8
> 12:  2  B  B  9
> 13:  3  B  B  1
> 14:  3  B  C  3
> 15:  3  A  B  4
> 16:  3  A  A  5
> 17:  3  A  C  6
> 18:  3  C  C  9
> ```

```
# dropping duplicates by position
drop <- CJ(1:3, 1:3)[V1 > V2, which = TRUE]
test[, CJ(c(a, b, c), c(a, b, c), sorted = FALSE)[,cn := .I][-drop], by = rn]
```

> ```
>     rn V1 V2 cn
>  1:  1  C  C  1
>  2:  1  C  B  2
>  3:  1  C  A  3
>  4:  1  B  B  5
>  5:  1  B  A  6
>  6:  1  A  A  9
>  7:  2  A  A  1
>  8:  2  A  C  2
>  9:  2  A  B  3
> 10:  2  C  C  5
> 11:  2  C  B  6
> 12:  2  B  B  9
> 13:  3  B  B  1
> 14:  3  B  A  2
> 15:  3  B  C  3
> 16:  3  A  A  5
> 17:  3  A  C  6
> 18:  3  C  C  9
> ```

For illustration, the created combinations have been numbered consecutively before being filtered. Filtering by position keeps the same combinations `cn` for each input row `rn`.

If all columns of `df` are to be used for creating combinations while keeping positions the code becomes finally

```
drop <- CJ(seq_along(df), seq_along(df))[V1 > V2, which = TRUE]
setDT(df)[, rn := .I] # execution order is important, drop needs to be computed first
df[df[, CJ(do.call("c", .SD), do.call("c", .SD), sorted = FALSE)[-drop], by = rn][
        , value := calc(V1, V2)][
          , dcast(.SD, rn ~ rowid(rn))], on = .(rn)][, !"rn"]
```

> ```
>                 a           b          c           1            2           3            4
>    1: -0.56047565 -0.99579872 -0.5116037 0.273177095  0.443480566  0.25211300 0.6889459178
>    2: -0.23017749 -1.03995504  0.2369379 0.051625832  0.214606608 -0.05310253 0.7330919071
>    3:  1.55870831 -0.01798024 -0.5415892 1.232435358 -0.027640410 -0.61203449 0.0003232368
>    4:  0.07050839 -0.13217513  1.2192276 0.004959116 -0.009276298  0.08246971 0.0173194151
>    5:  0.12928774 -2.54934277  0.1741359 0.016577155 -0.284877208  0.02226394 2.0147894919
>   ---                                                                                     
>  996: -0.08997520  0.07664366  1.0609662 0.008062943 -0.006872360 -0.09117496 0.0058570650
>  997:  1.07051604  0.25516476 -0.4455056 0.763607781  0.241500405 -0.38995947 0.0630771939
>  998: -1.35110039  0.27744682 -0.4291802 1.038675520 -0.318350818  0.45733970 0.0741577975
>  999: -0.52261670  0.53685602  1.1890118 0.241477031 -0.247305230 -0.48328838 0.2532570646
> 1000: -0.24919068 -0.46048557  0.8342941 0.060244308  0.108629008 -0.18888191 0.1923106299
>                  5          6
>    1:  0.411748217 0.23249043
>    2: -0.220263201 0.05462033
>    3:  0.009690796 0.25721165
>    4: -0.149412251 0.91088256
>    5: -0.367369972 0.02987264
>   ---                        
>  996:  0.078179132 0.75407734
>  997: -0.107667460 0.18105015
>  998: -0.112502154 0.16906373
>  999:  0.493676298 0.88118117
> 1000: -0.325108180 0.52830001
> ```

Comment: Okay, I like this way, however there is one thing I can't really understand. When I use this script on my dataset, columns (and apparently also rows somewhere) get mixed up somehow. Since I have 22 variables in my dataset, then I expect them to be named by following principles (however the program actually somehow mixes all columns):              
             x <- CJ(1:22, 1:22)[V1 >= V2]

Comment: Okay, can you please explain what exactly does do.call("c", .SD) within the code do? Sorry for multiple questions...

Comment: From my perspective this code works for me now, one last thing I guess. So when I am kinda thinking about order of calculations (looking at CJ(1:22, 1:22) [V1 >= V2]) I can't seem to determine in which order program actually saves all newly created columns. At using three vars per example it goes by order 11, 21, 22 which is quite logical, however  when using 22 vars, it seems as order is not following initial order of calculations (as stated in CJ). Do you have any ideas how to keep the order always the same (regardless of the number of vars used)?

Comment: This is a side effect of `[V1 >= V2]` which just compares *actual values* within each row, not positions. Without `[V1 >= V2]` the order always should be the same. Let me think how this can solved, perhaps `combinat::combn2()` could be a solution.

Comment: I understand, however I really prefer the commutative version (triggered by [V1 >=V2]), of course it does not make sense to do some calculations twice. Btw I appreciate your help, this really became an interesting problem and solution of course.

Comment: Yes, I got that, however as I am setting up a data reconfiguration program, which always works with same 22 vars, I tend to find a way, it doesn't mixes variables in which the calculations are saved. But as far as I see, if I use cancel sorting, order of vars seems okay... Do you have any idea, what is the main reason, the order gets changed, even with `sort = FALSE`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162637/discussion-between-gaspers-and-uwe).

Answer (score 2):

You could use a nested `lapply` to create the new columns, then use a nested `do.call` to bind them to your data:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(1000), b = rnorm(1000), c = rnorm(1000))
calc <- function(i,j)
{
  abs(i*j)/(i*j)*log(1+abs(i*j))
}

newcols <- lapply(df, function(x) lapply(df, function(y) calc(x, y)))

df_new <- cbind(df, do.call(cbind, do.call(cbind, newcols)))

> head(df_new)
            a           b          c           1            2           3            4            5            6           7
1 -0.56047565 -0.99579872 -0.5116037 0.273177095  0.443480566  0.25211300  0.443480566 0.6889459178  0.411748217  0.25211300
2 -0.23017749 -1.03995504  0.2369379 0.051625832  0.214606608 -0.05310253  0.214606608 0.7330919071 -0.220263201 -0.05310253
3  1.55870831 -0.01798024 -0.5415892 1.232435358 -0.027640410 -0.61203449 -0.027640410 0.0003232368  0.009690796 -0.61203449
4  0.07050839 -0.13217513  1.2192276 0.004959116 -0.009276298  0.08246971 -0.009276298 0.0173194151 -0.149412251  0.08246971
5  0.12928774 -2.54934277  0.1741359 0.016577155 -0.284877208  0.02226394 -0.284877208 2.0147894919 -0.367369972  0.02226394
6  1.71506499  1.04057346 -0.6152683 1.371548145  1.024122587 -0.72038540  1.024122587 0.7337098375 -0.494837621 -0.72038540
             8          9
1  0.411748217 0.23249043
2 -0.220263201 0.05462033
3  0.009690796 0.25721165
4 -0.149412251 0.91088256
5 -0.367369972 0.02987264
6 -0.494837621 0.32103592
```

Comment: This is also a very interesting solution I must say. However do you have any idea, how to disable creation of duplicated columns within _lapply_ function?